# How to run the cron job as a user instead of root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron

I have few bash scripts which are adding to cron jobs with specified timing, but it needs to be executed as root user. I am trying to run those scripts i.e., crob jobs but it needs root user permission, since I am running this jobs in ubuntu ec2 instance where root user is restricted. What would be the work around to run those scripts as root user.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with EC2, but you can define a list of commands which can be executed by `sudo` without password prompt. Run `visudo` and insert something like this:

```
Cmnd_Alias     CRONJOB = /full/path/to/command1, /full/path/to/command2, ...
<your_user>  ALL=(ALL)   ALL, NOPASSWD:CRONJOB
```

after that just use `sudo` in the bash scripts and put these in your cron job.

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/the/script1
* */2 * * * /path/to/the/script2
```

Comment: ubuntu ec2 instance by default does not ask for the password even if I includes sudo before any command but how do I prefix it in the cron job so that cron runs particular script with sudo prefixed to that

Comment: If you already includes `sudo` before the required commands, no need to put it in cron job.